# ClassCastException with spring-data JPA delete method

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

In my test class, I insert a test product in setUp and delete it in tearDown. During mvn package, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.myproject.app.entity.Product
at com.myproject.app.MyProjectProductTests.tearDown
```

This is my service method to remove product by name, which uses JPA:

```
public Product remove(String productName) {
    return repository.removeByName(productName);
}
```

In my repository I define removeByName as follows:

```
@Transactional
Product removeByName(String name);
```

and this is the tearDown in my test class:

```
....
@Autowired
private ProductServiceImpl productService;
....

@After
public void tearDown() {
    this.productService.remove(productNameToTest);
}
```

Why do I get that error for this tearDown?

Comment: so what does your removeByName() do?

Comment: It's a transactional method in repository. My aim is to remove the product by the given name.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: `removeByName` method has either declared `Integer` as a return type, and/or has declared query or native query which returns `int` (e.g. it returns number of items deleted (int) instead of the deleted `Product` item). Just guessing.

Comment: does your removeByName() work at all? I mean, outside unit tests? it doesn't sound like this problem relates to teardown at all, but faulty service method

Comment: and also, which spring data jpa version is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
@Transactional
Product removeByName(String name);
```

to me looks like a faulty signature. You can choose return value between an integer (return count of deleted entries) or list of VO:s (return all deleted objects). However, one object is not an acceptable return value. This should work:

```
@Transactional
long removeByName(String name);
```

and

```
@Transactional
List<Product> removeByName(String name);
```

and even

```
@Transactional
void removeByName(String name);
```

but not the thing you have.

Comment: This is the answer thank you. I'm new to java but I should have known about type casting.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating query `Product removeByName(String name);` to `Product deleteByName(String name);`

Comment: Same error. May be I shouldn't try to add a transactional method but write a custom repository method to delete instead.